# Can anyone please let me know where have I gone wrong in evaluating $\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) \cos^2(nt) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

> $\lim\int_{-1}^{1}  f(t) \cos^2(nt) dt$  = ? when $f$ is a continuous function on $[-1,1]$.

My try:

Let $\left| \int_{-1}^{1}  f(t) \cos^2(nt) dt\right|\leq \int_{-1}^{1} | f(t) \cos^2(nt)| dt\leq k\int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(nt) dt$ as $f$ is a continuous function on $[-1,1]$. So $\lim  |a_n| = 0$ as $\lim \int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(nt) dt = 0$. So $\lim  a_n = 0$.

[$\int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(nt) dt = \int_{-1}^{1}\cos(2nt)/2 dt = \frac{\sin(2n)}{2n}$, and $\lim \frac{\sin(2n)}{2n} = 0$]

Can anyone please let me know where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean value of $\cos^2(t)$ or $\cos^2(nt)$ is not zero, it is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the value of the wanted limit is half the integral of $f$ over $(-1,1)$, since by the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\cos(2nt)\,dt = 0$.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(nt) dt = \int_{-1}^{1}\cos(2nt)/2 dt = \frac{sin(2n)}{2n}$

$lim \frac{sin(2n)}{2n} = 0$                                                                                            is this wrong?

Comment: @cmi: yes, that was wrong. $\cos^2(nt)$ is a non-negative function, equal to $$\frac{\cos(2nt)+1}{2}$$

Comment: Where is my fault? Can you please mention? I know the answer and all this. I just want to know where is my fault?

Comment: I have just told you. $\cos^2(nt)$ and $\frac{\cos(2nt)}{2}$ **are not** equal.

Comment: okk then also 1 should be the answer..As  $ \int_{-1}^{1}\ \frac{1}{2} dt = 1$

Comment: No, the answer is $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\,dt$.